# MySQL transactions on 1&1

Tags: mysql, transactions

When connected to my local MySQL server, I can run the following queries without any problem:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO t VALUES(0.1, 0.2, 0.3);
ROLLBACK;
```

The entry is correctly inserted and then removed after the `ROLLBACK`.

Now, I tried the same queries on 1&1's phpmyadmin. The row is correctly inserted but the `ROLLBACK` never works. I also tried adding `SET autocommit=0;` before the transaction, with no success. It looks like any of the queries `BEGIN`, `START transaction`, `COMMIT`, `ROLLBACK`, etc. run on their servers will return no error but won't actually have any effect regarding transactions.

Why?

Comment: Is it possible you have an InnoDB table locally but the remote table is MyISAM?

Comment: I found it out with `SHOW TABLE STATUS`. Yes, you were right. So that means I can't use transactions?

Comment: from mysql command line: `show table status from mydatabase like 'mytable';`   or from phpMyAdmin view the list of all tables in the database.  Info is in the Type column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your remote table is a [MyISAM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/myisam-storage-engine.html) table while your local table is [InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-storage-engine.html).  The MyISAM table engine does not support transactions.  Unfortunately, it also will not complain when you use commands like 'BEGIN TRANSACTION' or 'COMMIT'.

You can change the table engine:

```
ALTER TABLE t ENGINE = INNODB;
```

There are other differences between the engines as well, the documentation will have the details.

Comment: Thank you! Also, I could easily change my table's type using `ALTER TABLE my_table TYPE=INNODB`.